# Evaluate a hierarchical query based on results from lower levels

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle Database 11g and bellow is a dummy table with dummy values, that I now try to explain:

I have a table that describes a relationship between IDs that represent "groups" and IDs that are the group's members. Members of the groups can be both simple members or some of the groups themselves (without cycles). As a result, some groups are simple groups of 1 level while some could have potentially many levels. Each group has a "minimum limit" value and each group member is of some value including a group when it acts as a member of that group.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to simply check, wheter a sum of groups member values is equal or greater than the minimum limit value of the group. That would be fairly easy if it wasn't of the hierarchy. The problem is that if one of the members is a group I can count with its member value **ONLY** if itself has enough member values to satisfy its minimum limit. So the evaluation needs to go from the leaf to root so that the lowest group is evaluated first and based on that are evaluated the higher levels of the hierarchy.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to figure it out. Can somebody help?
**Important note**: I would like to solve this without using R/CTE if possible. I can't accept any answer using CREATE keyword as I'm restricted to use it.

```
CREATE TABLE "MYGROUPS" 
(   
"MYGROUP_ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
"MYGROUP_LIMIT" Number, 
"MEMBER" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
"MEMBER_VALUE" Number
);

insert into mygroups
(Select 'g0'  ,1  ,'00'  ,1 from dual) union
(Select 'g1'  ,5  ,'01'  ,1 from dual) union
(Select 'g1'  ,5  ,'02'  ,1 from dual) union
(Select 'g1'  ,5  ,'03'  ,1 from dual) union
(Select 'g1'  ,5  ,'g2'  ,3 from dual) union
(Select 'g2'  ,3  ,'02'  ,2 from dual) union
(Select 'g2'  ,3  ,'05'  ,2 from dual) union
(Select 'g2'  ,3  ,'g3'  ,2 from dual) union
(Select 'g3'  ,5  ,'03'  ,1 from dual) union
(Select 'g3'  ,5  ,'05'  ,1 from dual)
```

This set of data should result in g1 OK, g2 OK, g3 NOT OK. G1 is dependent on g2, which in turn is not dependent on g3 to be OK and so the g1 is OK as well.

In this alternative set of data:

```
insert into mygroups
(Select 'g0'  ,1  ,'00'  ,1 from dual) union
(Select 'g1'  ,5  ,'01'  ,1 from dual) union
(Select 'g1'  ,5  ,'02'  ,1 from dual) union
(Select 'g1'  ,5  ,'03'  ,1 from dual) union
(Select 'g1'  ,5  ,'g2'  ,3 from dual) union
(Select 'g2'  ,3  ,'02'  ,1 from dual) union
(Select 'g2'  ,3  ,'05'  ,1 from dual) union
(Select 'g2'  ,3  ,'g3'  ,2 from dual) union
(Select 'g3'  ,5  ,'03'  ,1 from dual) union
(Select 'g3'  ,5  ,'05'  ,1 from dual)
```

G1 is NOT OK, because it depends on g2 which here is also dependent on g3 and so all three here result in NOT OK

Here's a query to get the idea. The 'OK' values evaluated the group as satisfying the minimum limit. 'NOT OK' is the opposite. 'DUNNO' is the problem where I don't know how I could evaluate it.

```
select connect_by_root mygroup_id as root, mygroups.*,level
from ( Select mygroups.*,
             sum(member_value) over (partition by mygroup_id) sum_of_values,
             CASE 
                  WHEN sum (CASE WHEN member like 'g%' THEN 1 END) over (partition by mygroup_id) > 0 THEN 'DUNNO'
                  WHEN sum(member_value) over (partition by mygroup_id) >= mygroup_limit THEN 'OK'
                  WHEN sum(member_value) over (partition by mygroup_id) < mygroup_limit THEN 'NOT OK'
             END eval
        From mygroups ) mygroups
connect by prior member = mygroup_id
```

Also, any of the groups can contain any number of different groups over any number of levels and the member-groups can possess different member_values in different groups.

Comment: Please show needed result of query

Comment: @Mike The result for this particular dataset would be: all g1 rows EVAL = OK, all g2 rows EVAL = OK, all g3 rows EVAL = NOT OK; Explanation: g1 minimun limit satisfaction is dependent on its member g2 since the other members add only to 3 out 5. g2's minimum limit is satisfied even without its member g3 since the other members add to 4/3. Since g2 is OK, g1 is OK as well. If the case was different and g2 was dependent on g3, than g2 would be NOT OK and so would be g1 because it is dependent on g2 in turn. Hopefully this is clear enough.

Comment: If g3 is OK then sum for g2 = 6, as it uses member_value of g3 (not a sum of g3 member)

Comment: @Mike Yes, if g3 were OK, then g2 would count with its member_value which is 2 so then the sum of usable member_values would be 6 out of needed 3 and g2 would also be OK and so would be g1. In this case however the g3 is NOT OK which is still fine for g2 who will do even without g3 member since the other members add up to 4 out of needed 3.

Comment: I know how to go from the leaves. I can collect the signs of "OK / NO" on the way. But only if the heirs - Groups is one. If more - it is possible to collect the amounts separately for each way only.

Comment: In general, I do not know how to solve the problem without the CTE. Can help user-defined functions, and / or package. Is it possible to use them if the result will be collected one request?

Comment: @Mike You can try posting an answer using R/CTE if you want. If there wasn't other way using e.g. just connect by, then I'd probably accept such answer as well. User-defined functions/procedures/temp tables (anything involving CREATE keyword in general) are out of my reach due to my DB user restrictions, so I can't accept any answer using those. Also note that each group can contain any number of rows over any number of levels. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve the problem with the "connect by". But I not find a way to pass the result of calculation to the next level of recursion.

With R/CTE encountered similar problems. And in addition were strong limitations due to the inability to use "group" and "window" functions in R/CTE. Attempts to use the "CTE alias" twice in recursive part (for join previous row) leads to ORA-06000 (internal server error) and drop connection to Oracle.

Today, it occurred to me to provide "R/CTE" recurive loop with help of a single row (hereinafter: "cursor row"), and to keep a state (list of OK-groups) in this "cursor row". Necessary data rows, numbered in advance in the order "from the leaves to the root", joined at each iteration to "cursor row" by row number.

```
with GRP as (
     select A.*, row_number() over (order by L) N
       from (
         select mygroup_id, min(level) L
           from  mygroups m
          start with not exists(select 1 from mygroups m2
                                 where m2.mygroup_id=m.mygroup_id and m2.member like 'g%'
                               )
        connect by member=prior mygroup_id
          group by mygroup_id
       ) A
),
Cursor_tab(mygroup_id,N,list,result) as(
   select NULL,N,lpad(',',2000),0
     from GRP where N=1
 union all
   select G.mygroup_id,Q.N+1,
          ltrim(Q.list)||decode(R.column_value,0,'',G.mygroup_id||','),
          TO_NUMBER(R.column_value)
     from Cursor_tab Q, GRP G,
          table(cast(multiset(
           select decode(sign(sum(member_value)-min(mygroup_limit)),-1,0,1)
             from mygroups m
            where m.mygroup_id=G.mygroup_id
              and (member not like 'g%' or Q.list like '%,'||member||',%')
          ) as sys.odcivarchar2list)) R
    where G.N=Q.N
)
select mygroup_id, decode(result,1,'OK','NOT OK')
  from Cursor_tab
 where mygroup_id is not null
```

Comment: Wow, crazy as this is, it really does seem to work correctly!! (Don't know about performance-wise, but that wasn't really the issue in my OP). You also gave me some new insights here for which I'm grateful. In case somebody else posted a correct answer not using R/CTE I'd have to change the accepted answer due to the OP. Thank you very much, it's crazy yet awesome :D

Comment: @Demo If there will "No CTE" solutions - write to me. Because right now this seems to me impossible. (Although yesterday and  "R/CTE" seemed unrealistic).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember the `MYGROUP_ID` and `MYGROUP_LIMIT` whilst constructing the tree so that you can re-use it. You're on the right track with `CONNECT_BY_ROOT`, but you're not storing the limit.

It's unclear whether a member's value should be double counted if they appear multiple times in the hierarchy. I've assumed that a member can be double counted as some have different values; to remove this you'll need an additional step to make your hierarchy unique on `MEMBER`, `STARTING_GROUP` and `STARTING_GROUP_LIMIT`

```
with all_hierarchies as (
 select member_value
      , connect_by_root mygroup_id as starting_group
      , connect_by_root mygroup_limit as starting_group_limit
   from mygroups m
connect by prior member = mygroup_id
        )
select starting_group
  from all_hierarchies
 group by starting_group
having sum(member_value) >= min(starting_group_limit)
```

It remembers all the necessary information and then assesses whether the members of the group are greater or equal to the limit. If you want to return all the data then you just need to join this query back to the hierarchy, something like:

```
with all_hierarchies as (
 select member_value
      , connect_by_root mygroup_id as starting_group
      , connect_by_root mygroup_limit as starting_group_limit
   from mygroups m
connect by prior member = mygroup_id
        )
, qualifying_groups as (
select starting_group
  from all_hierarchies
 group by starting_group
having sum(member_value) >= min(starting_group_limit)
       )
select a.*
  from all_hierarchies a
  join qualifying_groups q
    on a.starting_group = q.starting_group
```

This does use a CTE, but just for neatness. You can get rid of it if you want. I would consider using a recursive CTE as this is standard SQL and makes your query more portable.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid it's not what I'm looking for. Please look at my edit with alternative set of data. If I understand your query correctly, you check the sum of all lower level member_values against the limit of the root group. However, I need to check each level separately to know whether given member-group's member_value can be counted with in the sum of member_values that is checked against **that level's** limit. Btw: I didn't know I can use one CTE in the other CTE, thats awesome, thank you! I didn't want to use CTEs because they cannot be directly nested.

Comment: sorry @demo, I forgot that bit. I'm not near a computer at the moment, but that's just checking that the members of the hierarchy that are groups exist in the qualifying groups sub-query. I'll update the answer when I can.

Comment: Ok, I'm looking forward to it as I myself still don't see how it could be done. Note that the levels can be deeper than just 3 levels and that each level can contain any number of groups.